# Python - selenium и асинхронность

Tags: python, selenium, асинхронность, asyncio, coroutine

Есть ли возможность открыть сначала браузер для всех заданий, а потом перейти по ссылке ? Данный код выдает ошибку

```
import asyncio
from selenium import webdriver

async def get_html(url):
    driver = await webdriver.Chrome()
    response = await driver.get(url)
```

TypeError: object WebDriver can't be used in 'await' expression

Comment: Selenium синхронный, вы не сможете использовать его в асинхронном коде.

Comment: Что значит "открыть сначала браузер для всех заданий, а потом перейти по ссылке"? Сформулируйте точнее какая у вас цель

Comment: цель была сделать селениум асинхронным. Вопрос закрыт

Comment: @ValekPotapov: только неуместные или вопросы дубликаты закрываются на Stack Overflow. На полезные вопросы (которые могут помочь посетителям из гугла с похожей проблемой) можно и через 10 лет новый ответ добавить/поправить старый, если необходимо¶ Текущий вопрос или как слишком обширный можно закрыть или ограничится упоминанием, что `webdriver.Chrome()` не является awaitable (поэтому TypeError) и если вы уточните, что подразумевается под "открыть сначала браузер для всех заданий" (что это значит: вы хотите несколько ссылок в разных окнах открыть?)

Answer (score -1):

Благодаря HttpSession запросы можно делать асинхронными

Comment: старайтесь более развёрнутые ответы давать. Представьте вы к этой задаче через полгода вернулись, когда все детали уже забыли. Что бы вы хотели в ответе увидеть, чтобы решение повторить?

Comment: Тем временем полтора года таки прошло...

Comment: ...и ещё год...

Comment: ...И ещё год...